# add-ons in a linux installation of blender

Tags: add-on, linux

I have been trying to find a how-to or article which explains installing add-on .zips in Linux. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. It seems that there are a lot of add-ons available at Blender Market, like "Construction Lines" which only come as a .zip, but you can only see this after you have purchased. It seems the .zips don't install into the Ubuntu installation. Are they thought to work? Am I just doing something wrong? Is there a divide in the community or processes for making blender add-ons for Linux vs Windows? There doesn't seem to be much written about this, so I am thinking that I am just doing something wrong and perhaps it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using distro packages since they don't usually work well. Grab the binary from the [website](https://www.blender.org/download/) unzip it and double click on the executable to run it.

[image: binary to run]

Comment: Thank you Farid, that worked perfectly. It seems that the Ubuntu apt install of Blender could not use most add ons but installing from the Blender site gave me a platform where .zip add-ons worked easily.  Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: @poised it seems that if the comment "fixed" your issue then consider to accept the answer. Someone suggested this link on how the site works: blender.stackexchange.com/tour